# Flutter unique_identified library issue?

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I have a problem that when I used a library for flutter application to get the unique_id a problem arose where I can't do the build due that x-code can't import the required libraries even after pod installation was successful ,

Here is a screenshot of what the error would look like :

[image]

here is the exception stack trace when doing dart build :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           41.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
   ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/mac/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/unique_identifier-0.0.3/ios/Classes/UniqueIdentifierPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'unique_identifier/unique_identifier-Swift.h' file not found
    #import <unique_identifier/unique_identifier-Swift.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    /Users/mac/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-0.2.1/ios/Classes/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:146:75: warning: 'token' is deprecated: Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      [_channel invokeMethod:@"onToken" arguments:[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]];
                                                                              ^
    In module 'FirebaseInstanceID' imported from /Users/mac/Desktop/test/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:46:
    /Users/mac/Desktop/test/ios/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/Headers/FIRInstanceID.h:201:30: note: 'token' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (nullable NSString *)token __deprecated_msg("Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead.");
                                 ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from Headers/Private/FirebaseCore/FIRAnalyticsConfiguration.h:17:
    In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
    In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:180:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
            #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((deprecated(_msg)))
                                                          ^
    1 warning generated.
```

*** Update on the above [ the error above was corrected by removing the file and adding them again manually but now another problem appeared , when the code that get the unique Identifier is called exception happen ]

[image]

I appreciate the help

Regards,

Comment: Did you solve this?